# Need to Disable verification code emails when the user is not registered in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Azure B2C verification sends the verification code to every email address for forgot password. Even if the user is not registered in directory.

I am using custom policy but not able to get the expected results. Please find my the attached policy [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NWX_LaPt8TvM8VyriEbQQd-ic3AecYQo/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Comment: What is your goal and reasoning? Are you wanting to send them a different email if they don't exist? Doing _nothing_ would be an extremely bad user experience.

Comment: If the user does not exist in my azure ad b2c directory. I was hoping to throw an error stating user account does not exist so they does not receive the email.

Comment: This would allow a very easy [account enumeration](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1087/) attack. This is often a vector used for credential surfing and password reuse scenarios. Please don't expose your users to this.
The point of the email going to email accounts even if they don't exist is to prove they have access to that email address, after they enter the code it will tell them the account doesn't exist in the directory.

Comment: ok thanks for the information. But how account enumeration attack is achieved in the azure ad b2c?

Comment: If you 'throw an error stating user account does not exist' before they verify the email with the OTP, then an attacker can just try loads of email addresses and observe whether an error occurs or not

Answer (score 0):

I think your policy is missing some things, like 'LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress', which is what the 'PasswordReset' subjourney is calling from the 'CustomSignUpSignIn' user journey. Also, your 'SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email' looks empty (doesn't look like it's doing anything).

If those are truly empty (not not scrubbed for the internet), then you need to check for the user's email there. I would add a [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile) to check if the email exists by using the [AAD technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#protocol) (specifically AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress). If it does, the user should continue but if not, then throw an error here. You might need to add a meta key to [update the UI field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-or-sign-in-page-elements) to a custom error message, maybe unknown_error?

Comment: Hi will it be possible for you to provide an sample configuration to achieve this?